# PyInstaller-produced executable works from Conda shell but not normal shell

Tags: python, windows, pyinstaller, anaconda3

I have a .pyw file that I packaged into an executable (on Windows 10) with the following command from my Conda shell:

```
pyinstaller --onefile myfile.pyw
```

I can successfully run (it's a PySimpleGUI GUI, so "the GUI window loads" is the definition of success here) my application with (again from a Conda shell):

```
./dist/myfile.exe
```

However, if I run this same command from the same folder in a normal windows Command Prompt, nothing happens (no error, but the GUI window does not load). If I double click the exe from Windows Explorer, it also does not load (and again no error of any kind is displayed).

What do I need to do so that I can double click this exe and have it open the GUI?

Comment: Try `pyinstaller --onefile myfile.py`, then run it by `./dist/myfile.exe` in window command prompt to check if any exception.

Comment: @JasonYang It does not open my window, but it also does not produce any error message.

Comment: check os.environ dictionary in your conda and outside of it. There may be something differently set - and it prevents your code from running after packaging. Especially check value for path key. Sometimes there are libraries, which may be found in conda environment, but are not available after packaging.

Comment: @MaciejWrobel I’m certain there are things in Conda that are not also outside of it. So how would I package something with everything necessary to run outside of conda?

Comment: conda sets few environment variables, but difference may come from changes in env made by pynstaller (see https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/runtime-information.html). They may affect available libraries -  and you may want verify your sys.path list, if contains required paths.